# Still can't install wine since Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, wine, dependencies

I have been reading countless questions regarding issues about Wine on 14.04, and despite all that, I still can't install/compile it on my machine. *While you do have a lot of duplicate questions about this, I was unable to find an answer among them. Unless you're certain I missed the key answer, please don't marked this as a duplicate just yet.*

I used to have a working Wine install back on 12.04, but after the upgrade, the package couldn't be reinstalled for some unknown reason. I am now running Ubuntu 14.04 on a 64bit machine.

First, the problem is described as a dependency one, even though these dependencies don't seem to be resolvable through usual channels.

```
$ sudo apt-get install wine
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
```

Now, here are the things I tried after reading some questions about it.

- [Add `wine`'s PPA and install `wine1.7` directly](https://askubuntu.com/a/459304/175072).  Results in unresolved dependency for `wine1.7-i386`. The sources list had been correctly updated, and my system was up-to-date.
- [Remove `wine`'s user data directory and try again](https://askubuntu.com/a/483891/175072). No changes.
- [Install `wine1.7:i386` in order to get a 32-bit `wine` install](https://askubuntu.com/a/483891/175072). Results in unresolved dependency for `wine1.7-i386:i386`.
- [Install `ia32-libs`, now `lib32z1`, `lib32ncurses5`, and `lib32bz2-1.0`](https://askubuntu.com/a/74696/175072). These packages were already installed. Using `dpkg`'s `--force-architecture` switch on a .deb file didn't change a thing, same unresolved dependencies.
- Add `i386` to `apt-get`'s architectures and install `wine1.7:1386`: adding the architecture does not change a thing, even though `/var/lib/dpkg/arch` does contain `i386`.
- Install `playonlinux` instead. Same unresolved dependencies: `wine1.7-i386`.

I also came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528452/wine-not-installing-no-matter-what) in which the OP encounters a similar problem, with a lot of unresolved dependencies he forces an `i386` install through the `wine1.7-i386` package. Now, since I've added the `i386` architecture, I would expect these dependencies to be installed... Besides, I cannot really install these missing dependencies individually, since there's an entire dependency tree to be installed along with some of them...

I've been trying for some time now, but nothing seems to solve it. No matter what I try, `wine` won't install, and I can't find more information about the issue. Is there something I missed?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install wine wine1.6` (or 1.7 of course)

Comment: @DavidJones Same dependency issue.

Comment: `sudo apt-get -f install wine wine1.6`?

Comment: @DavidJones Same, holding broken packages on the way.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? I get the same issue. Searched google and tried some things including some you listed, but nothing helps. Pretty mystifying issue.

Comment: @pileofrocks Absolutely no solution. I tried everything I could think of, and everything I could Google but this thing remains stubborn as can be.

Comment: Did you call `apt-get update` after adding a new architecture to `dpkg`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Yes, I made sure that every change I brought to the package management system be taken into account before I try again :)

Comment: Alright, so don't ask me why, but for some reason, `apt` suddenly agreed to install `wine1.7` "naturally". I didn't update Ubuntu, didn't change any thing in my sources, and yet... it suddenly worked. I have absolutely no clue where that's coming from...